# Sharing ApplicationContext with Executors

Tags: java, spring, soap, executorservice

Let me clear agenda first:

1. I have 1000 request data.
2. I will read all the 1000 request and i will submit the 1000 request to executors.
3. Each task will hit the soap webservice and get the response.

Question:

1. I have shared application context which will be same for all the threads.
2. In the bean.xml file I have protoype bean which I want to use to make the soap request.
3. If I use the shared application context and get the proptype bean then will it be cause any synchrinizattion issue on shared app context variable.

Below is the sample code:

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
class AppContext
{
    ApplicationContext sharedContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

    public static ApplicationContext getAppContext()
    {
        if(sharedContext!=null)
        return sharedContext; //will this cause any isseu while accessing by multiple threads
    }

}

public class Testing {





    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        //here I tried to submit the task using ExecutorService and want to use the same application context
        //can I pass the prototypeBean in all the task with out synchronization issue?
        //because My appcontext is static so will it cause any issue while accessing my multiple threads

        ExecutorService service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        service.submit(new LoopTaskA(AppContext.getAppContext().getBean("myProtoTypeBean")));
        service.submit(new LoopTaskA(AppContext.getAppContext().getBean("myProtoTypeBean")));
        service.submit(new LoopTaskA(AppContext.getAppContext().getBean("myProtoTypeBean")));
        service.submit(new LoopTaskA(AppContext.getAppContext().getBean("myProtoTypeBean")));
        service.shutdown();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your `Runnables` do. If they're stateless beans and do not share/modify same variables/references with the other `Runnable`s, then generally you're safe. `getBean()` will return a new instance if the bean scope is *prototype*.

Be careful with the pool size, make sure you set a reasonable pool size(See [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html#heading4)). Also, make sure your worker Threads which make the web service request have proper timeouts set.

Comment: In my Runnable I will use the prototype bean to hit the webservice.
All my task are getting the prototype bean from the same application context
so do my same application context will cause any issue?
please help
Code will be same as I mentioned above

Comment: There's no problem in getting the worker beans from the same Application Context by different Threads. But if your worker beans share/modify same variables/references, then there is a problem.

Comment: what do you mean by share the same variable ,I think you mean sharing the singleton bean by the same application contex?
so if its prototype bean serving by application context so I dont have any problem

Comment: You need to read about Thread Safety http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-safety.html. For example, say that you keep a global counter simply as an `int` variable, and you update it after processing every request(from the worker threads), then your code is not Thread Safe - you have a Race Condition, so you need a proper locking or `AtomicInteger` to update this counter.